# SQL - PreparedStatement - Efficiency - JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Which is a better way to execute queries in JDBC

**Case 1**

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE ID = 1";
conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.executeQuery();
```

**Case 2**

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE ID = ?";
conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1,1);
ps.executeQuery();
```

**Note**

```
ps is PreparedStatement 
sql is String
```

I have to query for 1300 ID's (0 to 1299) each time.
Please do specify why that case is better...

I have read that PreparedStatement precompiles the query

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: We use Oracle as our backend . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ***second way is much better*** using `PreparedStatement` because it can make use of *prepared statement pooling* which increases performance.

### [Prepared Statement Reuse by caching](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/stmtcach.htm)

In the first part using `Statement` your statement is tied to a single data, which will have to create a new statement everytime for different data.

In case of Prepared Statement the same statement can be executed multiple times using different data.

**EDIT:**

> Can you please elaborate more about "Reuse by caching"???

Caching of `PreparedStatement`s is a ***transparent mechanism*** in which `Connection` maintains a pool of prepared statements, when you ask for a prepared statement with same SQL query then a cached one is returned. If there was no caching then a new one would have to be created everytime. *The feature is driver dependent.*

### Less Validation Overhead

When you use Prepared statement the query is validated only once, but when you use Statement it is validated every time

### Prevention of SQL Injection

*Not necessarily a performance perk*, but use of `PreparedStatement` will also save you from SQL injection attacks.

[Oracle Prepared Statement Caching](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/stmtcach.htm)

When you create an `OraclePreparedStatement` or `OracleCallableStatement`, the JDBC driver automatically searches the cache for a matching statement. The match criteria are the following:

- The SQL string in the statement must be identical (case-sensitive) to one in the cache.
- The statement type must be the same (prepared or callable).
- The scrollable type of result sets produced by the statement must be the same (forward-only or scrollable). You can determine the scrollability when you create the statement. (See "Specifying Result Set Scrollability and Updatability" for complete details.)

If a match is found during the cache search, *the cached statement is returned*. If a match is not found, then a new statement is created and returned. The new statement, along with its cursor and state, are cached when you call the `close()` method of the statement object.

Comment: I have added a link from Oracle Docs explaining statement caching in depth.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way would be to use a PreparedStatement

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE ID IN (?,?,?,?,?,.....)"
```

with 100 params and run 13 tasks 100 IDs each in parallel.

Comment: Didn't he mention that ID's are always 0 - 1299. If that is the case, wouldn't WHERE ID >= 0 AND ID <= 1299 be more efficient?

Comment: @ Sami Korhonen if he wants fixed IDs >= <= makes more sense but still parallel processing can increase speed several times